# I cannot find emails older than one or two years in my Outlook 2010.

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have used the technique of looking in the .pst data file,  however, still nothing older than 2 years.  I had emails saved in folders that were 3 to 4 years old and I want to recover them.  Where are they?  I did not delete them.  I am running Windows 7 which is very difficult to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

Search for an archive.pst on your machine. It is likely at some point when you weren't paying attention that Outlook was being helpful and archived older content to that data file, and you can open it to find your lost material.